# Where is the source of the high pressure oxygen supply system in this spacecraft life support system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The high-pressure oxygen in the cabin is supplied through a system of regulators and valves from a high-pressure oxygen tank. There are two pairs of the sub-systems of check valves, shut-off valves and nonreturn automatic shut-off valves in the system. The function of these valves is to stop the reverse flow of air from the cabin to the gas tank in the case of pressure drop and to close the line supply if there is some sudden pressure drop in header line or cabin in order to avoid the waste of the gas. Each pair of the valve systems consists of two alternative branches. One consists of a non-return automatic emergency shut-off valve, and the other consists of a check valve and a shut-off valve in series. Any branch of the two pairs is capable of supplying sufficient gas to the cabin. There are three alternative paths between the oxygen tank and the pair of valves. Oxygen can be transmitted to the cabin through either of the two regulators and the pair of valves connected to the regulator. It can also be transmitted to the cabin through a selector valve and either of the two pairs of valves.

[image]

Comment: What are you actually asking ... the book (etc) where the diagram and/or text was published? Or where you could buy an O2 system for your spacecraft? Or what?

Comment: Also, duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167630/can-anyone-help-find-the-source-of-high-pressure-oxygen-supply-system-of-a-spa

Comment: I tried to fix your question, but it doesn't look very well. It seems as if you had copy-pasted this text without knowing its meaning. Fix it fast, or your question will be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Oxygen tanks or H2O electrolysis (back to fuel cell as H2 and O2)